# Continuity of $f(x)= \frac{1}{3-x}$ at a $x=4$ point using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: analysis, inequality, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x)= \frac{1}{3-x}$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to show that $f$ is continuous at $x=4$.

We have $| f(x) - f(c) | = \left|\frac{1}{3-x}-\frac{1}{-1}\right| $.
Suppose also that $|x-4| <  \delta $. I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 4):

If $|x-4|<\frac12$, then $4-\frac12<x<4+\frac12$, and therefore $1-\frac12<x-3<1+\frac12$; in particular, $|x-3|>\frac12$. So, for a given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\min\{\frac\varepsilon2,\frac12\}$. Then$$|x-4|<\delta\implies\frac{|x-4|}{|x-3|}<\frac1{1/2}\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Initially, I let |x-4|<1/2. Thus, I got |x-3|<1. From here, I wasn’t sure what to do next. 
Now I see that when -1/2 < x-3 <  1/2 < 3/2 => |x-3|< 1/2 in particular. 
However, when we set take  = min{/2,1/2}, we normally take minimum so we meet 2 conditions, generally involving inequalities. Which two inequalities are we satisfying by taking the minimum?

Comment: By taking $\delta=\min\left\{\frac\varepsilon2,\frac12\right\}$, we make sure that, if $|x-4|<\delta$, then $|x-4|<\frac\varepsilon2$ and that $|x-4|<\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

$$| f(x) - f(c) | = \left|\frac{1}{3-x}-\frac{1}{-1}\right|=\left|\frac{4-x}{3-x}\right|$$

Notice that

$$\left|\frac{4-x}{3-x}\right|<\left|4-x\right|\quad\text{for } x<2 \quad\text{and}\quad4<x$$

This inequality is easy to prove.

So
$$\left|\frac{4-x}{3-x}\right|<\left|4-x\right|<\delta$$

Therefore, just take $\delta=\min\{\varepsilon,2\}$